# How to retrieve IndexedDB value data to variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, indexeddb

I have some data in a IndexedDB table that contains this data:

[image]

I then have this function to get data back from the IndexedDB (I need array with versions)

```js
function enter_base_and_get_versions() {
  var returnData = [];
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  var name = document.getElementById('Search_Bar_Templates').value;
  var transaction = db.transaction(['Formulars'], 'readwrite');
  var formulars = transaction.objectStore('Formulars');
  var request = formulars.openCursor();

  request.onsuccess = function() {
    var cursor = this.result;
    if (cursor) {
      if (cursor.value.name == name) {
        returnData = cursor.value.versions;
        defer.resolve(returnData);
        return defer.promise();
      }
      cursor.continue();
    } else {
      alert("Template doesnt exists");
    }
  };
}

function get_versions() {
  var myFormularsPromise = enter_base_and_get_versions();
  var myVersions = []

  $.when(myFormularsPromise).done(function(data) {
    myVersions = data;
  }).fail(function(data) {
    console.log("fail")
  });
}
```

When I try to print myVersions in function get_versions() it prints undefiend. I dont know how to save that array to javascript variable.

Comment: `enter_base_and_get_versions` returns nothing. You might need to move `return defer.promise();` to the end of the function.

Comment: It returns promise, because every time i tested statment if (cursor.value.name == name) was true. I made it to be true every time.

Comment: Where you put the `if (cursor.value.name == name) `? Also, where are you `try to print myVersions`? In the `done` chain?

Comment: @MoshFeu  Inside function: enter_base_and_get_versions() 12. line of code. I tried to print it inside done console.log(data) it prints undefiend.

Comment: Inside `enter_base_and_get_versions` you'll have access to the data but it doesn't **return** any of that. A function returns something only if it has a `return` statement in the end..

Comment: @MoshFeu Thank you for correcting me. I dont know how I didn't saw that. It returns inside onsuccess function.

Comment: Exactly.. It happens :)

Comment: @MoshFeu Now it prints inside Done, but when I print myVersions after done, at the end of get_versions() function it prints empty array

Comment: This is how synchronic code is working. The browser execute the code line by line, and only when the promise gets resolved, it runs its call back (the `done` function)

Comment: @MoshFeu Thank you. I thought I can save the value outside the async functions.

Comment: If you'll use [`async await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) it will **look** something like that (but under the hood it will do the same, means, put the code inside the resolved function).

Comment: @MoshFeu async and await did the job that I wanted. Thank you once more.

Comment: Glad to hear :) Good luck!